# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars , when i print barcharts by using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

**I have such Python code:**

```
import Regression as t
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
NN = t.Neural_Network()
yHat = NN.forward(t.X)
plt.bar([0,1,2],t.y, width = 0.35, alpha=0.8)
plt.bar([0.35,1.35,2.35],yHat, width = 0.35, color='r', alpha=0.8)
plt.grid(1)
plt.legend(['y', 'yHat'])
```

I would print bar charts for two numpy arrays but it shows errror like that

Comment: What package is ```Regression``` from?

Comment: What do 't.y` and `yHat` look like?